# Compounding in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of this format

```
Date        |   Return
01/01/2015       0.0
02/02/2015      -0.02
03/02/2015       0.05
04/02/2015       0.07
```

I would like to do compounding and add a column which will return Compounded return. Compounded return is calculated as:

- 1 for 1st row.
- (1+Return(i))* Compounded(i-1))

So my df finally will be

```
Date          |   Return  | Compounded
01/01/2015         0.0         1.0
02/02/2015        -0.02        1.0*(1-0.2)=0.8
03/02/2015         0.05        0.8*(1+0.05)=0.84
04/02/2015         0.07        0.84*(1+0.07)=0.8988
```

Answers in Java will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample is OK? In the second line the Compounded value don't should be 0.98?

Comment: Yes. It should be 0.98. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also create a custom aggregate function and use it in a window function.

Something like this (writing freeform so there probably would be some mistakes):

```
package com.myuadfs

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

class MyUDAF() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("Return", DoubleType)))

  def bufferSchema = StructType(StructField("compounded", DoubleType))

  def dataType: DataType = DoubleType

  def deterministic = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer(0) = 1.0 // set compounded to 1
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    buffer(0) = buffer.getDouble(0) * ( input.getDouble(0) + 1)
  }

  // this generally merges two aggregated buffers. This means this 
  // would not have worked properly had you been working with a regular
  // aggregate but since you are planning to use this inside a window 
  // only this should not be called at all. 
  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    buffer1(0) = buffer1.getDouble(0) + buffer2.getDouble(0)
 }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = {
    buffer.getDouble(0)
  }
}
```

Now you can use this inside a window function. Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Window
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("date")
val newDF = df.withColumn("compounded", df("Return").over(windowSpec)
```

Note that this has the limitation that the entire calculation should fit in a single partition so if you have too large a data you would have a problem. That said, nominally this kind of operations are performed after some partitioning by key (e.g. add a partitionBy to the window) and then a single element should be part of a key.

Answer (score -1):

First, we define a function `f(line)` (suggest a better name, please!!) to process the lines.

```
def f(line):
    global firstLine
    global last_compounded
    if line[0] == 'Date':
        firstLine = True
        return (line[0], line[1], 'Compounded')
    else:
        firstLine = False
    if firstLine:
        last_compounded = 1
        firstLine = False
    else:
        last_compounded = (1+float(line[1]))*last_compounded
    return (line[0], line[1], last_compounded)
```

Using two global variables (could be improved?), we keep the Compounded(i-1) value and if we are processing the first line.

With your data in **some_file**, a solution could be:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('some_file').map(lambda l: l.split())
r1 = rdd.map(lambda l: f(l))
```

> `rdd.collect()` 
>    [[u'Date', u'Return'], [u'01/01/2015', u'0.0'], [u'02/02/2015', u'-0.02'], [u'03/02/2015', u'0.05'], [u'04/02/2015', u'0.07']] 
>   `r1.collect()` 
>   [(u'Date', u'Return', 'Compounded'), (u'01/01/2015', u'0.0', 1.0), (u'02/02/2015', u'-0.02', 0.98), (u'03/02/2015', u'0.05', 1.05), (u'04/02/2015', u'0.07', 1.1235000000000002)]

Comment: Are you sure this would work when you have more than one (local) executor? The global would be different in each executor...

Comment: I tried implementing it but it fails when I have many number of days. Maybe its because of what Assaf suggested.